# Cannot call 'start' of undefined when starting backbone.js history.

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I get `Cannot call 'start' of undefined` when calling...

```
    Backbone.history.start()
```

When running some checks Backbone returns the object but Backbone.history returns undefined.

What could be the cause of this?

Thanks

Comment: This problem went away for me when I entered the url followed by a '#' character.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Do you have any routes on the controller? Backbone only creates the history once at least one route is specified.

More:

> TypeError: Cannot call method 'start' of undefined**
>
> Hmm, for some reason Backbone.history is undefined, and so there is no
>   start method on it. It turns out that Backbone.js creates an instance
>   of Backbone.History (upper case ‘H’) called Backbone.history (lower
>   case ‘h’) once a controller has been created that has at least one
>   route specified on it. This makes sense, as history management is only
>   required if there are routes to respond to.

http://tinnedfruit.com/2011/04/26/testing-backbone-apps-with-jasmine-sinon-3.html

Comment: I set the window.router to a base router before I call this. New to backbone though so I might not fully understand the question.

Comment: What did you do to get it working? I'm also setting `window.router` to something before I call `Backbone.history.start()`, but still getting an error.

Comment: (And that "something" is a router with multiple routes.)

Comment: Another cause can be including Backbone.js twice.  Seems trivial but comes up when developing plugins / extensions.

Comment: I fixed this by instantiating my router subclass. Just defining the subclass doesn't initialize it, and thus history remains undefined.

Answer (score 10):

I hit the same error.

This happens when you do not make an instance of the router:

```
var routerInstance = new blogRouter();
```

Comment: I actually have an instance (http://dpaste.com/06NK3KD) but it's not finding the way to the default function.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using CoffeeScript and your Router is defined using the CoffeeScript class keyword with a constructor method, double check that you invoke super in the definition of the constructor. This resolved the issue of Backbone.history being null for me.

```
class AppRouter extends Backbone.Router
  constructor: (options) ->
    super(options)
    # other initialization code
```

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you include `jQuery.js` **before** `underscore.js` and `backbone.js` in HTML head.

Answer (score 2):

I faced exact same issue for different reason, after spending couple of hours i realized that a method in my router "route" : function() is causing the issue, after i comment this unnecessary extra method, history.start() worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

A similar error message ".. has no method 'start'" pops up if you write `Backbone.History.start` instead of `Backbone.history.start` (the correct one is with lowercase `h` in `history`).

Answer (score 1):

```
(function($) {

    var Demo = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes:{
            '*actions':'defaultRoute'
        },
        defaultRoute:function(action){
            alert('xss');
        }
    });

    var demo = new Demo;
    Backbone.history.start();
    //My site http://bbs.w3hacker.com

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: To improve the quality of your post, please include how/why this code will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Also using old versions of jquery could cause this