# Trouble to get Backbone.Router to work with coffeescript

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

This is driving me crazy right now. I cannot get a simple router to work...

```
    jQuery ->
        class MyRouter extends Backbone.Router
            routes:
              ""            :"index"
              "/list"       :"showList"
              "/item/:id"   :"showItem"
            index: =>
              alert "index"
            showList: =>
              alert "get the lists"
            showItem: (id)=>
              alert "the item #{id}"

         @app = window ? {}
         @app = window.app ? {}
         @app.myRouter = MyRouter
         Backbone.history.start()
```

I always get this error:
 `index.js:50Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'start' of undefined`

and I saw this: [Cannot call 'start' of undefined when starting backbone.js history.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343357/cannot-call-start-of-undefined-when-starting-backbone-js-history)

but it did not help =(...

I am sure this is an easy one but I am some sort of stuck here ... 
please help...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't create an instance of a Backbone.Router, so `Backbone.history.start()` will fail.

```
@app.myRouter = new MyRouter()
```

The link you posted tells you exactly what the problem is:

> TypeError: Cannot call method 'start' of undefined**
>
> Hmm, for some reason Backbone.history is undefined, and so there is no start method on it. It turns out that Backbone.js creates an
>   instance of Backbone.History (upper case ‘H’) called Backbone.history
>   (lower case ‘h’) ***once a controller has been created*** that has at
>   least one route specified on it. This makes sense, as history
>   management is only required if there are routes to respond to.

Comment: @silverfighter I've read that exact post you linked trying to puzzle out why my router wasn't working just the other day too. :)