# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'start' of undefined on Backbone.history.start()

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

I'm using Rails. I just installed the `backbone-rails` gem and followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails).

When I try to do `Backbone.history.start()`, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'start' of undefined
```

I understand that `Backbone.history.start()` can't be called until after you create at least one route, according to [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343357/cannot-call-start-of-undefined-when-starting-backbone-js-history). That doesn't seem to be my problem, though, since I do have multiple routes, defined in this CoffeeScript file:

```
class Lunchhub.Routers.RestaurantLocationsRouter extends Backbone.Router
  initialize: (options) ->
    @restaurantLocations = new Lunchhub.Collections.RestaurantLocationsCollection()
    @restaurantLocations.reset options.restaurantLocations

  routes:
    "new"      : "newRestaurantLocation"
    "index"    : "index"
    ":id/edit" : "edit"
    ":id"      : "show"
    ".*"        : "index"
```

Why am I getting this error?

Edit: here's my code:

```
<div id="restaurant_locations"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    window.router = new Lunchhub.Routers.RestaurantLocationsRouter({restaurantLocations: <%= @restaurant_locations.to_json.html_safe -%>});
    Backbone.history.start();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: are you creating an *instance* of any route before calling `Backbone.history.start()`?

Comment: Compare the behavior of http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/a5SLF/ versus http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/a5SLF/1/, the second one has `new R` whereas the first one does not.

Comment: I think I am. I made an edit to include my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating an instance of the router with the new keyword before calling `Backbone.history.start`.

EDIT: Backbone.history must be `undefined`, which as others have said is typically because [there needs to be a router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343357/cannot-call-start-of-undefined-when-starting-backbone-js-history) with at least one route active before Backbone creates this object.

> Backbone.js creates an instance of Backbone.History (upper case ‘H’)
>   called Backbone.history (lower case ‘h’) once a controller has been
>   created that has at least one route specified on it

I see you're creating a new instance of the router but it's possible that a bad Router instance is still the issue, just a different flavor than discussed in other issues -- check the `typeof` your `window.router` object router  before your `Backbone.history.start()` call. Does it return what you'd expect?

EDIT: As confirmed in the comments below, the `RestaurantLocationsRouter` is somehow bad. We've yet to figure out why, but creating a new router works as expected and indicates that indeed something has gone awry with your router instance.

Comment: I think I'm doing that already, but I could be wrong. I made an edit to include my code.

Comment: Can you check the `typeof` of your window.router object to see what it's returning?  It's possible that it's not actually an instance of `Backbone.Router`.

Comment: It looks like it's an instance of `RestaurantLocationsRouter`. Its `typeof` is `object`.

Comment: And if we're looking for evidence of whether `window.router` is a valid router, I can enter `window.router.routes` into the console and it returns what I'd expect (several routes).

Comment: Thanks. I'm running out of debug ideas. What browser are you on BTW?

Comment: Chrome. I think I just made a development. If I create a new router, it works. I added this: `var Foo = Backbone.Router.extend({routes: {"foo":"bar"}}); r = new Foo();` and that made the error go away. So my `RestaurantLocationsRouter` must be invalid for some reason. Now the question is why.

Comment: We've figured out why I'm getting the error I was getting and how to make it go away. I consider this question answered, and I would consider the question of why `RestaurantLocationsRouter` is invalid to be a different question. If you update your answer to say (in a more conclusive way) that my router is bad, I'll accept it.

Comment: Good work figuring that out. Sorry we haven't yet gotten as to why the router is bad, but it's a good sign that you're able to move forward with a more vanilla router. I'd be interested to see to what you're CoffeeScript is compiling. I also might look into your as I haven't used it before and don't see a reset method in the Router object description (http://backbonejs.org/#Router).

Comment: sorry, you "might look into your `@restaurantLocations.reset` method"

Comment: No problem. Thanks for helping me get this far. I'll look into that `reset` method.

Comment: I figured out the problem. It turned out to be somewhat ridiculous (on my part). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215062/backbone-js-router-instance-is-somehow-invalid/11215570#11215570