# 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'Backbone.$(window).on('hashchange', this.checkUrl)')

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, backbone-routing

I'm trying to configure Router with Backbone.js and receiving an exception at line 1414 of backbone.js 1.1.2

The error exists with Safari and Chrome:

```
[Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'Backbone.$(window).on('hashchange', this.checkUrl)')
start (backbone.js, line 1414)
(anonymous function) (index.html, line 27)
```

Here's the index.html file, line 27 is Backbone.History.start()

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    </div>
    <script src="../jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="../backbone.js"></script>
    <script src="../json2.js"></script>

</body>

<!-- BACKBONE -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
        var PageRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
            routes: {
                '': 'index'
            }
        });
        var pageRouter = new PageRouter();
        pageRouter.on('index', function() {
            console.log('hey');
        });
        Backbone.history.start();
    })(jQuery)
</script>
</html>
```

I can't find many resources to help out, and most of the pre-existing resources emphasize the allocation of the Router, and I feel it's implemented correctly. Also, I don't think it's necessary to have a Collection or Model since I'm only trying to implement routing at this time. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

** EDIT **

I reordered the script imports to:

```
<script src="../underscore.js"></script>
<script src="../backbone.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../json2.js"></script>
```

and the error changed to `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'Backbone.$(window)')`

adding the breakpoint to line 1414 of backbone.js indicates the error is from evaluating `this.checkUrl`

```
checkUrl: function () { [native code] }
arguments: (...)
get arguments: function ThrowTypeError() { [native code] }
set arguments: function ThrowTypeError() { [native code] }
caller: (...)
get caller: function ThrowTypeError() { [native code] }
set caller: function ThrowTypeError() { [native code] }
length: 1
name: ""
__proto__: function Empty() {}
[[TargetFunction]]: function (e) {
[[BoundThis]]: Backbone.History
[[BoundArgs]]: Array[0]
```

the way I set up the router is de facto according to multiple sources, irrespective of the `(function($){})(jQuery)` and dunno how to get the path to be assigned correctly. using `#` did not help me.

Comment: how about putting a breakpoint at that line in the code?

Comment: backbone.js shows: Local{docMode:undefined, fragment:"", frame:undefined, loc:undefined, oldIE:null, options:undefined, this:Backbone.History{ _hasPushState:false, _wantsHashChange:true, _wantsPushState:false}}

Comment: tried passing options {pushState:true}, and defining `index: function() {}` in the `extend`, all aforementioned result with `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`, and couldn't find solution from previous post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343357/cannot-call-start-of-undefined-when-starting-backbone-js-history

Comment: Does your Backbone version have `Backbone.$`? Does your jQuery have `on`?

Comment: @muistooshort yes, as far as I can tell, created gist: https://gist.github.com/aug2uag/11099133

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice two things in your code:

1. The [`routes` object](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-routes) is supposed to map route patterns to method names (or anonymous functions):

   > The **routes** hash maps URLs with parameters to functions on your router (or just direct function definitions, if you prefer)

   but you don't have an `index` method defined in `PageRouter`.
2. If you look at the [`route` docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-route) (or the [Catalogue of Events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog)), you will see that:

   > The **name** argument will be triggered as a `"route:name"` event whenever the route is matched.

   So your router will trigger `'route:index'` events, not `'index'` events.

I can't reproduce the error you're seeing but if I address both of those points, things seem to be working as expected:

```
var PageRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'index'
    },
    index: function() {
        console.log('index');
    }
});
var pageRouter = new PageRouter();
pageRouter.on('route:index', function () {
    console.log('hey');
});
Backbone.history.start();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/kt7L8/

Comment: thank you for correcting my code, and indeed verifying that the source works for you, and the kind and generous response. there is the same issue that persists, and I am getting the same error, and only the error changes when I rearrange the order of importing source scripts.

Comment: Is there any chance that you can reproduce the problem at jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com? Might be easier to spot if I could see it happen.

Comment: yes, the file works on jsfiddle, can be seen at http://jsfiddle.net/aug2uag/cgwGr/

Comment: believe it or not, code would not work for me with the js assets, and works fine with importing source from cdnjs. i dunno what, perhaps version mismatches, but sticking with cdnjs. Thanks for your help!

Comment: also, json2 was not necessary